# Uncaught Error: QWeb2: Error while extending template 'ClientDetailsNo expression given

Tags: odoo, qweb

Getting this error when trying to extend a qweb template. Has anyone come across something like this. I've not been able to find anything related to this.

```
Uncaught Error: QWeb2: Error while extending template 'ClientDetailsNo expression given
http://localhost:8069/web/content/246-17d551a/web.assets_common.js:2444Traceback:

Error: QWeb2: Error while extending template 'ClientDetailsNo expression given
at Object.exception (http://localhost:8069/web/content/246-17d551a/web.assets_common.js:2444:7)
at Engine.extend (http://localhost:8069/web/content/246-17d551a/web.assets_common.js:2482:507) 
at Engine._render (http://localhost:8069/web/content/246-17d551a/web.assets_common.js:2477:454)
at Engine.render (http://localhost:8069/web/content/246-17d551a/web.assets_common.js:2477:151)
at Class.display_client_details (http://localhost:8069/web/content/313-25bfa95/point_of_sale.assets.js:337:1375)
at Class.line_select (http://localhost:8069/web/content/313-25bfa95/point_of_sale.assets.js:332:528)
at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8069/web/content/313-25bfa95/point_of_sale.assets.js:327:86)
at HTMLTableSectionElement.dispatch (http://localhost:8069/web/content/246-17d551a/web.assets_common.js:740:451)
at HTMLTableSectionElement.elemData.handle (http://localhost:8069/web/content/246-17d551a/web.assets_common.js:713:173)
```

*Code*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">

<t t-extend="ClientDetails">
  <t t-query="div.client-details-right" t-operation="append">
    <div class="client-detail">
        <span class="label">RNC</span>
        <span class="detail client-phone">Test</span>
    </div>
  </t>
</t>
```

Comment: Can you show how you extended the template, the stack trace itself is not enough

Comment: Sure, I'll post it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a typo in the attribute name for the jQuery selector -- it should be [`t-jquery`, not `t-query`](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/qweb.html#id3):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">

    <t t-extend="ClientDetails">
        <t t-jquery="div.client-details-right" t-operation="append">
            <div class="client-detail">
                <span class="label">RNC</span>
                <span class="detail client-phone">Test</span>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>

</templates>
```

Comment: It's t-jquery?!?!? never saw the "j" there. *facepalm*. But I'm still getting the same error. :(

Comment: @JoanBarros, have you done a full reload of the POS page?

Comment: I must say there's something going on with that code and my brain. I derped out again and I spent about 25 minutes figuring out why It didn't work.

I wrote `t-tquery` instead of `t-jquery`... :/